# Get output of bash from openshift client back to shell

Tags: bash, powershell, sh, openshift

I am trying to automate reading image versions in our openshift platform.

I am using powershell to call a batch script (*.sh). With that batch script I am connecting to openshift client and get the name and current versions of that specific image. Thats working.

Now I am trying to get the output of the openshift client (that means the output of the batch script) back to powershell, so that I can store it in excel.

```
oc login $OPENSHIFT_SERVER_URL --username=$USERNAME --password=$PASSWORD

oc describe dc -n <MY_NAMESPACE> | grep Image | awk -F '[:/]' '{print $(NF-1)", "$(NF)}'
```

How can I "send" the output of that bash script, which is calling commands via openshift client, back to powershell?

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `powershell`?

Comment: I call the bash script with powershell

Comment: Just add "$results =" to be the beginning of the line.  Standard output will go to the new variable.

Comment: "Batch" or "Bash"?